# Logging with Retrofit2 without OkHttp intercept

Tags: android, retrofit2

I want to log the complete request (url, request param, body) of retrofit2 request without using okHttp Library. How can it be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add logging-interceptor:

> compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
>   compile
>   'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'

```
OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
                httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
                builder.networkInterceptors().add(httpLoggingInterceptor);

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                        .addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor).build();

retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(NetworkConstsParkCloud.BASE_URL)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .client(client)
                        .build();
```

there are no shortcuts, you can not use retrofit without okhttp, As of 4.4, HttpUrlConnection on Android uses OkHttp under the hood anyway:
https://github.com/google/agera/issues/22

Answer (score -1):

> A Simple class made by me
>   Advantage

1. Common class to call api
2. Progressbar handler in built no need to show or dismiss
3. Log in your own logger with format
4. Multipart inbuilt i.e.

   `HashMap<String, File> fileParams = new HashMap<>();`
   `if (selectedImage != null) fileParams.put("image", new File(selectedImage));`
   `Retrofit.getInstance("user/editprofile", params, fileParams)`

> Retrofit common class

```
/*
 * Created by RajeshKushvaha on 19-10-16
 */

public abstract class Retrofit implements Callback<ResponseBody> {
private static final String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.1.100/apps/demo/web/v1/"; //Local

private ProgressDialog progress;

public Retrofit() {
}

public Retrofit(Context context) {
    if (progress != null && progress.isShowing()) {
        progress.dismiss();
    }
    progress = new ProgressDialog(context, R.style.ProgressDialog);
    progress.setIndeterminate(true);
    progress.setIndeterminateDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape_drawable_progress));
    progress.setCancelable(false);
    progress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    progress.show();
}

public Retrofit(Context context, boolean isLoadMore) {
    if (isLoadMore) return;
    if (progress != null && progress.isShowing()) {
        progress.dismiss();
    }
    progress = new ProgressDialog(context, R.style.ProgressDialog);
    progress.setIndeterminate(true);
    progress.setIndeterminateDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape_drawable_progress));
    progress.setCancelable(false);
    progress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    progress.show();
}

public static Call<ResponseBody> getInstance(String endPoint,
                                             HashMap<String, String> params) {
    return getInstance(endPoint, params, null);
}

public static Call<ResponseBody> getInstance(String endPoint,
                                             HashMap<String, String> params,
                                             HashMap<String, File> files) {
    HashMap<String, RequestBody> bodyParams = null;

    Logger.e("URL", BASE_URL + endPoint);
    if (files != null && files.size() > 0) {
        bodyParams = new HashMap<>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
            Logger.e("params", entry.getKey() + "\t" + entry.getValue());
            bodyParams.put(entry.getKey(), createPartFromString(entry.getValue()));
        }
        for (Map.Entry<String, File> entry : files.entrySet()) {
            Logger.e("params", entry.getKey() + "\t" + entry.getValue().getPath());
            String fileName = entry.getKey() + "\"; filename=\"" + entry.getValue().getName();
            bodyParams.put(fileName, createPartFromFile(entry.getValue()));
        }
    } else {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
            Logger.e("params", entry.getKey() + "\t" + entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    //Added for handle timout you can skip this
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

    ApiInterface apiInterface = new retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build().create(Retrofit.ApiInterface.class);

    return bodyParams != null ? apiInterface.methodMultipart(endPoint, bodyParams) : apiInterface.method(endPoint, params);
}

@Override
public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
    if (progress != null && progress.isShowing()) progress.dismiss();
    String body = null;
    try {//Converting string to JSONObject
        if (response.body() != null) {
            body = ((ResponseBody) response.body()).string();
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(body);
            Logger.e("Response", call.request().url().toString() + "\n" + object.toString());
            onResponse(response.code(), object);
        } else {
            body = response.errorBody().string();
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(body);
            Logger.e("Response", call.request().url().toString() + "\n" + object.toString());
            onFailed(response.code(), object.optString("message"));
        }
    } catch (JSONException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        if (body != null) Logger.e(body);
        onFailed(response.code(), "Something went wrong!\n Please try again");
    }
}

@Override
public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
    Logger.e("Response", call.request().url().toString() + "\n" + t.toString());
    if (progress != null && progress.isShowing()) progress.dismiss();
    if (t instanceof ConnectException || t instanceof SocketTimeoutException || t instanceof UnknownHostException) {
        onFailed(0, "Failed to connect with server!");
    } else if (t instanceof IOException) {
        onFailed(0, "No internet connection!");
    } else if (t instanceof RequestException) {
        onFailed(0, "Request timeout!");
    } else {
        onFailed(0, t.getMessage());
    }
}

public interface ApiInterface {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST
    Call<ResponseBody> method(@Url String endpoint,
                              @FieldMap HashMap<String, String> fields);

    @Multipart
    @POST
    Call<ResponseBody> methodMultipart(@Url String endpoint,
                                       @PartMap HashMap<String, RequestBody> fields);
}

private static RequestBody createPartFromString(String value) {
    return RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), value);
}

private static RequestBody createPartFromFile(File file) {
    return RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
}

public abstract void onResponse(int statusCode, JSONObject jResponse);

public abstract void onFailed(int statusCode, String message);
}
```

> How to use (for Post method)

```
HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("email", email);
        params.put("password", password);

        Retrofit.getInstance("user/login", params)//user/login was endpoint
                .enqueue(new Retrofit(ForgetPasswordActivity.this/*pass context if you want progressbar*/) {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(int statusCode, JSONObject jResponse) {
                        //handle your response
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailed(int statusCode, String message) {
                        showToast(message);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Logging as in Logs prinitng :D

Comment: Why downwote?, sorry not get you :(