# How to show a progress dialog along with a long operation and retrofit?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-asynctask, retrofit, progressdialog

I have a long process which is used for converting the selected images from gallery to byte array and use that to build a model class, and i set this model class to the retrofit as as the raw request body. Since image conversion takes some time, as well as the retrofit request , showing a progress dialog will always ends in a crash.

```
   private class EmailAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
    getBytesFromBitmap(selected.get(i).sdcardPath, i + ""); //here i'll get the image byte arrays

     emaildocumentsList.add(documentsmail);
     emaildocuments.set(emaildocumentsList); //here i'll set the modelclass
 Retrofit retrofitApi = new Retrofit.Builder().addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).client(okHttpClient)
                            .baseUrl(BASE_URL_PROD).build();
                    RetrofitApi requestApi = retrofitApi.create(RetrofitApi.class);
                    String encodedHeader = "Basic " + "d2VzdGxha2VtYXJrZXRpbmc6TFJVN0xiR1pvdDZpMHQ3T3p3UnpsVTRxdkQ2UGRJZjU=";
                    retrofit2.Call<ResponseBody> responseBodyCall = requestApi.EmailAttachUploader(encodedHeader, cookies,emaildocuments);
                    responseBodyCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                            progressbuilder.dismiss();
                            if (response != null) {
                                if (response.body() == null) {
                                    //Toast.makeText(MultipleImageSelectGalleryActivity.this, "Exception: {Nullpointer Exception}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    setResult(524);
                                    finish();
                                }
       }
          @Override
         public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                            progressbuilder.dismiss();
                            //Toast.makeText(MultipleImageSelectGalleryActivity.this, "Upload Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            setResult(524);
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
}
 @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressbuilder.show();
    }
```

Every time the error shows **window leaked** along with **cannot create looper inside**, here I'm showing the progress dialog in onpreexecute method, then also it happens.
 How to resolve this issue?

Comment: check this my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41277575/logging-with-retrofit2-without-okhttp-intercept/41277944#41277944 progress dialog inside.

Comment: why are you using async task for retrofit call?...for progress dialog start the dialog before you retrofit call and dismiss that inside the onresponse and onfailure.

Comment: onpreexecute i'm showing the progress dialog, since image conversion is a long process, i have to wait till it finishes for building the model class. @AnkushBist

Answer (score 1):

First thing to note is that, don't run the "Retrofit" code inside the "**AsyncTask**", since **Retrofit** runs on it's own background thread.
So, every time you run it inside "**AsyncTask**", the "**AsyncTask**" will finish before the **retrofit** has completed the execution.

Secondly, initialize the "**ProgressDialog**" outside the **Retrofit** code and start it. Then, in the response callback method dismiss the "**ProgressDialog**".
That's it.

Comment: Haven't you seen that i'm converting the images into byte array, i have to wait for that process to finish so that i can build the model class for the retrofit.

Comment: ohk now i got it. But you dont need to use async task here if you are working with retrofit. you can do this like create a method in which you retrofit call will run and add a few steps to that before retrofit like start dialog and convert image to byte array. And rest to dismiss dialog you have already done that in the above code